# What are some strategies for working multi-threading into libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm in the process of writing a library that deals with long-running tasks like file downloading and processing large amounts of text. I want to multi-thread this library so that these tasks won't freeze up the applications that use them.

Do you have any advice for doing so in a structured manner, or specific classes I should use/avoid? I was thinking of using the `IAsyncResult` interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx, or perhaps some BackgroundWorkers.

Comment: Personally, I think these decisions should be left up to the user of your library. Document that it can block for a long time and recommend using a BackgroundWorker but leave it up to them.

Comment: @Zan Lynx: Good idea. Would you recommend exposing a `sync` version and an `async` version of each long-running method, though? Perhaps through an override?

Comment: @Zan: Sometimes, I agree - however, in many cases, providing an asynchronous API up front has some huge advantages, since you (as the library designer) can optimize things more effectively if you know in advance that things will be used asynchronously.  In addition, this shows the user of the API that it *can and should* be used in an asynchronous fashion.

Comment: This is a good example, btw - file downloading can and should be asynchronous internally - there's no real reason to serialize that process...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so that these tasks won't freeze up the applications that use them.

If this is your goal, you should look into the standard asynchronous programming patterns in the framework.

If your library is targeting .NET 4, have it return `Task` and `Task<T>`, as this will ease transition into the async support coming in the next release of C# and VB.NET.  This also has the very nice addition of allowing synchronous usage with no extra work on your part, since the user can always just do:

```
var result = foo.BarAsync().Result; // Getting Task<T>.Result blocks, effectively making this synchronous
```

If you're targeting .NET 3.5 or earlier, you should consider using the [Event-based asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx), as it is used in more of the current APIs than the APM.

Comment: Very good points. Is this what you are referring to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: Yes.  That's the preferred mechanism for asynchronous development from .NET4 onwards.  The language is going to leverage this directly in vNext, so you can make async code look nearly synchronous.